# PHP Mysql Ajax Photo Gallery with Album

Tags: php, mysql, css, ajax, photo-gallery

Please Help, the photo gallery of my website was denied in my defense because it uses google+ for uploading photos, can anyone suggest or give me script or tutorial on making a photogallery with albums and CMS. Please help.PLEASE.

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/cool-jquery-gallery/

Comment: This is OT for SO, so it'll probably be RIP ASAP but FWIW I use gallery3 for back-end image database stuff. It's very customizable - although it takes a little while to see how.

Comment: it doesnt work on windows

Comment: @Strawberry "database"? Didn't you mean "DB"?

Comment: @MrLister :-) Slipped up, I mean SNAFU - sorry